# How do I find where the vowels are in a string input and have them print in the output?

Tags: python-3.x

I have to write a script where it prompts the user for a string, the code takes the string and finds where each value is. For example, if I put in "apple", the output would be 0 and 4. The script has to have two functions, where the first asks for user input and the second finds the vowels.

I have asked my teacher, and he led me to what I have now, but I cannot get it from there.

```
def askForString():
    theString=str(input("Please enter a string: "))
    theString=theString.lower()
    return theString

def findVowels(TheString,vowels):
    for i in range(len(TheString)):
        if TheString[i] in vowels:
            TheString=TheString[i]
            return [i]

def main():
    TheString=askForString()
    vowels="aeiou"
    TheVowels=findVowels(TheString,vowels)
    print(TheVowels)

main()
```

Comment: Instead of immediately returning `i` (this will only output the first match) you should append values of `i` to a list and return that list when the `for` loop is finished. You should also get rid of the `else` part.

Answer (score 0):

```
string = input("Enter a line of text: ")
vowels = set("aeiou")
for index, char in enumerate(string):
    if char in vowels:
        print(index)
```

If you input 'apple', it returns '0' and '4'.

If you input 'ukulele', it returns '0', '2', '4', '6'.

Just split the above into your two functions.

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved conveniently with a dict, if you've gotten that far:

```
def vowelFinder(mystring):
    vowels = ('a','e','i','o','u')              #tuples are preferable for efficiency
    results = {}                                #dict for {vowel:[position list]} pairs
    for x in vowels:
        for y in range(len(mystring)):
            if x in results.keys() and x == mystring[y].lower():
                results[x].append(y)                              #alter a dict entry
            elif x = mystring[y].lower():
                results.update({x:[y]}                            #make a dict entry
    return results
```

Note use of str.lower() to avoid missing capitalized vowels. Then if we try something like:

```
vowelFinder('I have asked my teacher, and he led me to what I have now, but I cannot get it from there.')
{'a': [3, 7, 18, 25, 44, 50, 66],
 'e': [5, 10, 17, 21, 30, 33, 37, 52, 73, 86, 88],
 'i': [0, 47, 63, 76],
 'o': [40, 55, 69, 81],
 'u': [60]}
```